# Port was already in use

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, port

I'm developing spring boot application. Everything was great, until another restart. Now i always get this error on Windows 10:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.
```

For every port

```
Web server failed to start. Port 27010 was already in use.

Web server failed to start. Port 9090 was already in use.
```

i tried to seek the process using port by `netstat -ano` and got nothing. Reload doesn't help, administrator mode on Intellij IDEA too. As you see, changing port doesn't help and i think that the problem is deeper, maybe there are couple of active instances of application, but i cant find them and terminate

EDIT: SOLUTION

In `application.properties` was defined a static IP of PC. When Internet connection have changed, tomcat became unable to bind any of ports, because of DHCP

Comment: 0 port doesn't work too, any port. Maybe reason is embedded tomcat server

Comment: it mean to say 8080 is in use

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni but netstat shows nothing

Comment: There might be an instance running from your inteij please check

Comment: Open the Windows task manager. Are there processes called "java" in there? If so, those are the likely culprits holding on to the ports.

Comment: @Gimby restarted everything, killed all java process, stopped postgresql server, anything. Renewed JDK, `gradlew bootRun` with killed IDE also gives this error

Comment: I found the trouble, in sometime my pc have changed network connection to another WIFI point and static defined IP in .properties became incorrect, so application couldn't bind port

Comment: Wow, that's a really misleading error message then. "Port already in use" is miles away from "cannot bind port".

Comment: I faced this problem since start working remotely, I do not know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the application from intellij and re run. You might have missed it.